# How to load properties in Jenkins before allocating a node

Tags: jenkins

I've seen a few questions about loading property files in jenkinsfiles, but the solutions all seem to require wrapping readProperties in something that allocates a node which may be slow. Jenkins already accessed the jenkins file from SCM, so it should have all the information it needs to grab a property file from SCM, also.

I was thinking I could do an http request to git to get it, but then I saw this: "SCM-specific variables such as GIT_COMMIT are not automatically defined as environment variables; rather you can use the return value of the checkout step." But the checkout step would be after a node, also, right?

If I try to call readProperties at the top level, it gives me 'Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing'

Answer (score 0):

SCM variables are available in the scm object, so this is doable using a PRIVATE-TOKEN header against the gitlab API and parsing the json response.

Also, there is a simpler way:

```
readTrusted: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#readtrusted-read-trusted-file-from-scm
```

This will read the contents of a file in SCM and then you can call readProperties text:content on it.